# Why is this constant stored in the .section .bss?

Tags: assembly

I was looking over an assembly program and it had this:

```
.section .bss
 .equ BUFFER_SIZE, 500
 .lcomm BUFFER_DATA, BUFFER_SIZE
```

Why is the BUFFER_SIZE constant constant stored in the buffer area of memory instead of .section .data? Is it because the constant is directly related to the buffer? If so, why can't the constant just be stored in .section .data?

Comment: `BUFFER_SIZE` isn't being stored. It's an equate (`.equ`) so it's a symbol only used by the assembler to define the constant 500. It's like using a `#define` in C.

Comment: `BUFFER_SIZE` isn't stored in the BSS; it's an assemble-time constant (`.equ`).  It's "stored" in the instruction stream as an immediate in instructions that use it.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I got the word wrong. But why is it put in .section .bss and not elsewhere? Does it not matter at all where the statements are put? Thanks for the correction btw.

Comment: Right, it doesn't matter where `.equ` directives appear; they're in effect for the whole asm source file, not just within sections.  Defining it next to the buffer whose size it is just makes more sense than putting it anywhere else.  And BTW, I think the source you're looking at is from Programming From the Ground Up.  There's an SO question where these lines appear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005954/how-do-you-make-an-x86-assembly-program-in-linux-that-converts-files-to-uppercas.